# How to translate "so" with "donc" and "alors"?

Tags: grammaire, anglais, choix-de-mot, conjonctions

"So" is one of the most common connecting words in English, and I often have trouble translating it to French.

Sometimes I just translate it directly to *alors*, as in "Il avait froid, alors je lui ai donné ma veste."

But I'm under the impression that the more common way to translate it is to use *donc*, but I'm never clear on exactly where among the words of the sentence *donc* should be placed.

Comment: In the example you're using, a native speaker could also say : "Je lui ai donné ma veste parce qu'il avait froid".

Comment: J'ai trouvé une [réponse à ta question](http://www.reddit.com/r/French/comments/1y6ljg/la_diff%C3%A9rence_entre_donc_et_alors/cfi805u) avec laquelle je suis plutôt en accord.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In most cases it's best to translate *so* (the one that starts a proposition<sup>1</sup>) with *donc* used as an adverb<sup>2</sup>, not as a conjunction. It suggests a light natural follow-up.

> Il avait froid, je lui ai donc donné ma veste.

If the meaning of *so* is close to “*hence*” or “*from this observation*” (like in your example), then you may use *alors*.

> Il avait froid, alors je lui ai donné ma veste.

But this has a strong flavor of oral communication<sup>3</sup>. This *alors* may conveniently be added while the sentence is being spoken, but *alors* should normally only be used as a “*then*” (temporal or conditional). So<sup>4</sup>… you may want to reformulate. In the following sentence, “*comme*” should be understood somewhat like “given that”<sup>5</sup>, and this is the preferred form in writing.

> Comme il avait froid, je lui ai donné ma veste.

Last, if *so* is meant as a logical conclusion you may want to use *donc*, in this case, as a (coordinating) conjunction.

> Il avait froid, donc je lui ai donné ma veste.

—
<sup>1. But not the one in “*so be it*” or “so to say”, which is an “*ainsi*”!</sup>
<sup>2. Place it where you would place *pas* in a negative sentence.</sup>
<sup>3. Just like using *so* in English, you may say, but English's oral phrasings certainly pervade much more into writing than French's.</sup>
<sup>4. I'll let you guess ;-)</sup>
<sup>5. But *given that* best translates as “*étant donné que*”.</sup>

Comment: So *donc* can be an adverb. That was the part that always confused me, seeing a conjunction used as an adverb. That particular construction is very counter to English tendencies.

Comment: Inside a sentence it's an adverb or a particle (it has the same strange hybrid status as *pas*).

Answer (score 1):

*Donc* and *alors* can be both used as a translation for *so* in most of the case. You <strike>must</strike> can (see my comment) use *donc* instead of *alors* when you can replace *so* by *therefore* (http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/therefore.html).

Example :

> You read my message so you must understand why *donc* is more used
>   than *alors*

Becomes in french

> Tu as lu mon message donc tu dois comprendre pourquoi *donc* est plus
>   utilisé qu'*alors*.

I used *donc* because the *so* of the original sentence can become a *therefore*.

Comment: I "must"?? That doesn't make much sense to me. Needs more clarification! Then when would I use *alors*? Cases where *so* means *therefore* are the only ones I'm asking about. I've seen translations like this: *Elle ne comprend pas, alors il faut l'aider :
She doesn't understand, so we need to help her* and that uses *alors*...

Comment: My answer is maybe a bit confused. When I spoke about therefore it was to show you the logical implication. Have a look at these links, they explain the think better than I could : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ernFuOcfpTU and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ernFuOcfpTU . Sorry again for my bad answer.

Answer (score -6):

The best way to translate *so* to French is with using *alors*.

Comment: Except in the many many cases where it isn't. There isn't a one-for-one correspondence here.